# Cognitive Services via CLI in Azure Government

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-cli, azure-gov

The docs mention that it can be accessed via CLI, but there are no samples for CLI in the docs, only PowerShell.

Any advice on where to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the details on how to manage Cognitive Services in the [Cognitive Services Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/cognitiveservices?view=azure-cli-latest) documentation.

As usual with Azure Government:

- Set your CLI to Azure Government via the `az cloud set --name=AzureUSGovernment`
- Use the Azure Government regions.
- Use the [subset of APIs available in Azure Government](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-services-aiandcognitiveservices#cognitive-services) (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/cognitiveservices/cognitiveservicesaccounts/create#definitions_kind) doc for the literal values to use with --kind).
- Use the [subset of SKUs available in Azure Government](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-services-aiandcognitiveservices#cognitive-services)

Here's a quick sample on how to get going:

```
az cloud set --name AzureUSGovernment
az login

az group create -n cogstestrg -l usgovvirginia

az cognitiveservices account create -n cogstestcv -g cogstestrg --sku S0 --kind ComputerVision -l usgovvirginia

az cognitiveservices account show -g cogstestrg -n cogstestcv

az cognitiveservices account keys list -g cogstestrg -n cogstestcv

#Make sure you REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_KEY in the curl command below using the key from the previous command
curl -v -X POST "https://virginia.api.cognitive.microsoft.us/vision/v1.0/analyze?visualFeatures=Categories,Description,Color&details=&language=en" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_KEY" --data-ascii "{'url' : 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Shaki_waterfall.jpg'}"
```